# Can I create interaction plots even if I am missing combinations of my two independent variables?

Tags: anova, interaction

I am relatively new to statistics and I am conducting some statistical analyses on a dataset. My dataset has two categorical, independent variables A and B. A has 7 potential values and B has 18 potential values. I also have a dependent variable, C. I want to see how C is affected when the values of A and B are changed and I want to create interaction plots to visually show this interaction.

However, due to the nature of my data, there are certain combinations of A and B that do not and cannot exist in my dataset. So far, I have run a Two-Way ANOVA against A and B as well as the interaction between A and B and the P Values show significance for all three.

My questions are as follows:

1. How does the missing pairs caveat affect my ability to look at the interaction between A and B?
2. Are there other things that I should be aware of or watch out for while analyzing my data as a result of those missing combinations?

Thank you all for any and all assistance you could provide!